# How vscode parses json files that are used for extension configurations?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

How VSCode parses json files like `language-configuration.json` that is used to describe language extensions? I see that these files contain comments and many, like typescript, contain [trailing commans](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/d9e91c33351c051876c731485a0c47a5852b904b/extensions/typescript-basics/language-configuration.json#L179).

If such content is parsed using `JSON.parse()` the error will be raised.

I implement an extension that reads these config files and like to use the same parsing method that is used in vscode.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would assume they use the `jsonc-parser` - since it is written by one of the vscode team and has 3 million+ downloads a week.

[npm package: jsonc-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonc-parser)

I use it myself because I need to parse complicated custom settings that might have comments in them for example.

Add the package to your dependencies. `npm install --save jsonc-parser`

Then import it (I have it in a js extension for now):

`const jsonc = require("jsonc-parser");`

`const rootNode = jsonc.parseTree(document.getText());`

Comment: Thank you. I will look for this package in the VSCode. Can you tell me if this package support comments and trailing commans in JSON objects?

Comment: As I said I use it for json with comments.  I bet it works for trailing commas as well.  I see it appears 30 times in the vscode github repository.